# JQuery get left and top positions from div based on parent div

Tags: jquery, position

I have a draggable divs inside another div and need to get the left and top positions from child div.

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child1" style="position:absolute;"></div>
<div id="child1" style="position:absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

At the moment i get the positions from childs based on the first placement:

```
$('#iframe_main').contents().find('.button".$key."').draggable({ 
    containment:'#parent',
    scroll: false,
    drag: function(event) {
        o = $('#iframe_main').contents().find('.child').offset();
        p = $('#iframe_main').contents().find('.child').position();

}});
```

So if i place the child in the right bottom corner of #parent and move it back to the left top corner i get negativ values.

What i want is the left and top postion from child divs based on #parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the position of both element. Please see below.

This is an example what you can make.

```
$('#iframe_main').contents().find('.button".$key."').draggable({ 
    containment:'#parent',
    scroll: false,
    drag: function(event) {
        o = $('#iframe_main').contents().find('.child').offset();
        p = $('#iframe_main').contents().find('#parent').offset();

        childtop = o.top - p.top;
        childleft = o.left - p.left;
        console.log(childtop + " " + childleft);

}});
```

Comment: Okay the new positions look fine. Is it possible to change it by drag the div? At the moment this is a fixed value. Thanks.

Comment: yes is possible. get the value directly inside drag event. see example with : console.log(childtop + " " + childleft);

Comment: Perfect! My copy paste fault :-)  Merci